# Not able to see Run Elevated option for .sln files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

When I try to run a vs solution file, I cant do it with run elevated access...as that option is not showing up on right click.

Comment: Can you be little more specific about what type of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in VS.  If your program requires UAC elevation to do its job then you have to ask for it in your program itself.  So it will still operate correctly on the user's machine.  Edit the manifest of your EXE project as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7/2818776#2818776).

To debug such an app, Visual Studio needs to be elevated itself.  It normally prompts you for that, but there's a bug in VS2013 that prevents that from working if the Visual Studio Hosting Process option is turned on.  Avoid this bug, and the prompt, by starting VS elevated.  Do so by right-clicking the shortcut and selecting "Run as Administrator".